# pipe's stdin.flush() hangs forever

Tags: python

I have a python application running on the kivy gui platform, and communicating with an AI game engine via

```
self.katago_proces = subprocess.Popen(
                command,
                startupinfo=startupinfo, # STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW on windows
                stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                shell=False,
            )
```

The two outputs are continuously checked in threads, while the input is written to as needed.

```
with self._lock:
    if self.katago_process:
        # store query + callback
        try:
            self.katago_process.stdin.write((json.dumps(query) + "\n").encode())
            self.katago_process.stdin.flush() # <- this hangs forever
        except OSError as e:
            self.check_alive(os_error=str(e), exception_if_dead=True)
```

This has worked without issues, sending hundreds of queries to the engine and getting results back fine.
However, in a new feature which automatically submits a query in the callback from another one (automatically playing out a game to the end), I'm seeing stdin.flush() hang forever, breaking the application.

Specifically on exit, I print the stack tracebacks using:

```
for threadId, stack in sys._current_frames().items():
    print(f"\n# ThreadID: {threadId}")
    for filename, lineno, name, line in traceback.extract_stack(stack):
        print(f"\tFile: {filename}, line {lineno}, in {name}")
        if line:
            print(f"\t\t{line.strip()}")
```

Which outputs something like:

```
# ThreadID: 22216 - a message queue waiting for user input, as expected
# ThreadID: 23044 - the stderr read thread waiting at .readline() as expected
# ThreadID: 26552 - self.katago_process.stdin.flush() , the problematic call that hangs, originating from the stdout read thread
# ThreadID: 8504 - the main gui thread printing this.
```

Checking with the debugger, I can confirm that the process/pipe is still there, i.e. process.poll() is None. This is expected, as otherwise there would be an OSError anyway. Calling flush in the debugger also hangs forever.

What could cause flush to hang forever, and what can be done about it?

This is on windows by the way, I have not been able to reproduce it on linux, although this could also be a gpu speed issue. Slowing down the queries (by asking for more calculation) also prevents the issue. It looks like some kind of weird race condition in the core library to me.

Comment: A write to a FIFO can only be flushed successfully if something on the other side is actually trying to read from it. So -- is that process _actually trying to read from its stdin_ at the time that you're doing this write?

Comment: Probably the place I'd debug this from would be a trace with a full-system tracing tool like [sysdig](https://github.com/draios/sysdig) so you can see if the process that's supposed to be reading actually has an ongoing `read()` syscall at the time of the attempted write; if it had a read call that exited earlier, when and why it exited, etc.

Comment: sysdig doesn't look like it works on windows. The engine is compiled from source though, and I can definitely check if it's reading, although it will take a bit of time.

Comment: Ah. There could be gotchas on Windows I don't know about; my experience is very Linux-centric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was almost certainly this:

`# ThreadID: 26552 - self.katago_process.stdin.flush() , the problematic call that hangs, originating from the stdout read thread`

Since the C++ program tries to write+flush, while the thread that is supposed to read this output is in turn flushing, they get deadlocked occasionally.

I solved this by making a write queue+thread such that all the flushing to the external program is done in a separate thread.